# Can see wifi connections, but cannot connect

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, internet

I have a Ubuntu laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, and I cannot connect to a wireless network. I can do that fine by an ethernet cable but it's getting really annoying.... I can see it fine, I click connect and it loads and then fails. It worked for some time, and randomly just started to fail more and more until it stopped working completely. Also an interesting thing is, that when it was working and I accidentally disconnected from the Wi-Fi, I wasn't able to connect again... If someone knows how to fix it I would love that....

Answer (score 1):

First check your wireless interface with the following command and Verify that your network device ("wlan0"?) is working & your wireless network is detected:

```
iwconfig

iwlist scan
```

Use the following command to change the channel:

iwconfig wlan0 channel #

where wlan0 is the name of your interface and # is the channel number you wish to switch to. After you have run that command, the channel is set to the new number of your choosing.

change 802.11bgn to 802.11bg.

```
iwconfig wlan0 modu 11g
```

Change wpa encryption to CCMP

```
wpa-pairwise CCMP
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ace@Ace:~$ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
--------------
wlan0 No scan results
lo Interface doesn't support scanning.
eth0 Interface doesn't support scanning.
------ When i try to change the channel:
Errorforwirelessrequest"SetFrequency"(8B04):
SETfailedondevicewlan0;Operation not permitted.
[none of the other ones worked, not permitted]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the parameter of wireless driver as follows and check the reported issuse.

> change 802.11bgn to 802.11bg.
>
> change the wep encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option it will work best.
>
> Set your wireless channel in the router to 1 or 11 then save the router configuration and reboot it.
>
> Go into network manager at top right corner of the screen and click on edit connections>wireless tab and set IPV6 to ignore.

Now open the terminal CTRL+ALT+_T then copy and paste the following code one line at a time for accuracy:

```
echo "options rtl8192ce swenc=1 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ce.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8192ce
sudo modprobe -v rtl8192ce
```

IF the issue persists, try compiling new driver. Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add that I'm a real noob with Ubuntu could you please explain those steps? I got the one with IPV and terminal but no idea what to do or where with those first 3 ....